# UWP - Refresh ListView from a running async method

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I have written a method which sends an UDP broadcast und recieves the results in a loop which are instantly written in to a `List<String>`. Since I'm using `ReceiveAsync()` it is running asynchronous.

My question is: how can I refresh the ListView in my UI each time the loop adds a string to my list. So I want the results to be displayed instantly on the screen as they appear in the list.

Code

```
do
{
    UdpReceiveResult result = await sclient.ReceiveAsync();
    ipList.Add(result.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString());
    // after this step I want the ListView to get refreshed
} while (sclient.Available != 0);
```

XAML ListView Code

```
<ListView x:Name="lbIps" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="174"
Margin="450,151,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="298" />
```

Code behind XAML

```
 public async void btnBroadcast_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    await ND2.run();
    lbIps1.ItemsSource = ND2.ipList;
 }
```

Comment: How are you displaying the ListView? If you are binding your UI to the ipList you probably just need to call `OnPropertyChanged("ipList")` whenever the list is updated.

Comment: In my MainApp.xaml.cs I run my asynchronous UDP-method. After it is done/ or canceled I use lvIp.ItemsSource=UDPMethodClass.IpList;. So it displays the results after the cancelation of my Task.

Comment: You should post that code as well and post the XAML where you want the list to be displayed. Really, if you want this to be updated as the ipList is populated you should bind the itemsSource in the XAML and call `OnPropertyChanged()` when it needs to be updated.

Comment: Use *ObservableCollection* as your items source.

Comment: @Lithium: How do I bind the itemsSource in XAML and where/how do I call OnPropertyChanged() ?
Romasz: if I use ObservableCollection as ItemsSource, it can't be convertred to a list, which i need as paramater. Does it work if I'll convert it with toList() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should bing the data to the `ListView` using data binding:

```
<ListView x:Name="lbIps" ItemsSource="{x:Bind IpList}" ... />
```

Now you have to actually create such property in the code-behind:

```
ObservableCollection<string> IpList => ND2.ipList;
```

Finally, change the type of `ipList` to `ObservableCollection<string>`. You no longer have to set the `ItemsSource` manually inside the `btnBroadcast_Click` method as it is bound directly to the `ND2.ipList`. Also, thanks to the fact that it is a `ObservableCollection<string>` any new items added will automatically be reflected in the UI.

**Note: ** Make sure, you don't create a new instance of the `ipList`, because the `ListView` would stay bound to the original instance. I presume `ipList` is a field or a property:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ipLIst {get;} = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

Now the property is initialized at the beginning and will not change. You can use `Clear()` method to remove all elements in the collection if necessary instead of setting a new instance.

Comment: I tried this, just how you explained this. But now I get an exception at ipList.Add(...); It sais: an interface, which was marshalled for an other Thread, was called by the application.

Comment: i actually fixed it now, it works completly! I just had to change ipList.Add(..) into:                          
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { ipList.Add(message); });

Comment: Great :-) . It is important to work with `ObservableCollection` on the UI thread, otherwise you get this exception :-) . Happy coding!